# batch: replacing dash from filename, says cannot find file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to replace a dash (surrounded by spaces) with a single space in filenames.

```
chcp 65001
set "file=%~1"
set "newfile=%file: - = %"
if "%file%" neq "%newfile%" ren "%file%" "%newfile%"
```

this fails with files that have some sort of dash that is apparently different somehow. the set command accepts these and replaces the dash just fine but the rename fails, claiming `The system cannot find the file specified`.

Comment: A quick tip: `if not FOO equ BAR` can be changed to `if FOO neq BAR` [for simpler logical thinking.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120009/is-the-checkbox-not-not-unchecked/120219#120219)

Comment: You're welcome. Can you show the content of `%file%` and `%newfile%`?

Comment: `%file%` copied from command prompt: `sorrows - part 1.mp3`, copied from explorer: `sorrows – part 1.mp3` so `%newfile%` will be `sorrows part 1.mp3`. the dash looks longer than usual when copies from explorer.

Comment: That's because it is not a dash, but [en dash](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=%E2%80%93&rlz=1C1CHZL_zh-TWHK745HK745&oq=%E2%80%93&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.910j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: My command prompt cannot find the difference between: hyphen, en dash, em dash, so I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) types. So you have to run multiple string substitutions to remove all of them from file name before running the __IF__ and if necessary the __REN__. For such purposes I use shareware file manager Total Commander (GUI application) which has a very easy to use but very powerful multi-rename tool built-in supporting even Perl regular expressions on file names which makes this task very easy to accomplish within a minute with a few clicks and typing just a few characters.